# How to insert value of my checkbox to different column in database codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

This should be like this

**ID|access1|access2|access3|**

and values:

**1|1|0|1**

//myController

```
    $basic_data = array();

    $select_access1 = $_POST("select_access1");
    $select_access2 = $_POST("select_access2");
    $select_access3 = $_POST("select_access3");
    $select_access4 = $_POST("select_access4");
    $select_access5 = $_POST("select_access5");

    $basic_data[] = array('accs_trans_sec'=>$select_access1,'accs_acctng_sec'=>$select_access2, 'accs_admin_sec'=>$select_access3,'accs_dashboard_sec'=> $select_access4, 'accs_reports_sec'=>$select_access5);

    $this->RoleModel->saveRole($basic_data);
```

//myModel

```
public function saveRole($basic_data)
{
    foreach($basic_data as $value) {
        $this->db->insert('roles_global_access', $basic_data);
    }}
```

Comment: Is there any error show? I think there's no need to use `foreach` on model.

Comment: there is no error.  i already update my model into

public function saveRole($basic_data)
  {
     $this->db->insert('roles_global_access', $basic_data);
 }

Comment: Please check first if you are getting the data properly on your `$_POST.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548173/how-to-insert-the-value-on-my-checkbox-to-different-column-on-my-database

check this one

Answer (score 0):

You can set that data to array just like this:

```
$data = array(
    'column1' => 'My Value 1',
    'column2'  => 'My Value 2',
    'column3'  => 'My Value 3'
);
$this->db->insert("table_name", $data);
```

Comment: i use checkbox and also ajax to pass the value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548173/how-to-insert-the-value-on-my-checkbox-to-different-column-on-my-database

check this one

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you are getting the values of your checkbox based on your `$_POST` variables.

Since you've declared `$basic_data` as **array()** no need to cast it as *$basic_data[]*.
So on your controller it should be like this:

```
    $basic_data = array(
        'accs_trans_sec'=>$select_access1,
        'accs_acctng_sec'=>$select_access2,
        'accs_admin_sec'=>$select_access3,
        'accs_dashboard_sec'=> $select_access4,
        'accs_reports_sec'=>$select_access5
    );
```

And your model there's no need to use loop since you are inserting `Object data` it should look like this:

```
public function saveRole($basic_data)
 {
    $this->db->insert('roles_global_access', $basic_data);

    return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
}
```

so basically, if the model returns **true** then it successfully inserted the data.

To check if data is inserted successfully:

```
 $result = $this->RoleModel->saveRole($basic_data);

   if($result == true){
    echo ("Successfully inserted!");
   }else{
     echo ("Problem!");
   }
```

Comment: Yes, I understand, but before going on `Inserting data` is your $_POST has a value? You can **`die($_POST['select_access1']);`** to check if they have values.

Comment: where I can try that. I'm sorry i'm beginner to codeigniter

Comment: Use `die($_POST['select_access1']);` on your controller. Then call the function on your browser to check if the data is passing successfully or not.

Comment: public function sample(){
  die($_POST['select_access1']);
 }

then i echo it on my view to check. it doesn't work

Comment: So it returns a blank page? You are not getting data from your form. Can you post the html form where the data is selected? (checkboxes)

Comment: check the picture that I upload

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548173/how-to-insert-the-value-on-my-checkbox-to-different-column-on-my-database

check this one

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not getting post data in the correct way. With `$_POST` have to use square brackets `[]`.

Second, Don't use `foreach` loop in the model

Get data in the controller like this

```
  $basic_data = array(
    'accs_trans_sec' => $_POST['select_access1'],
    'accs_acctng_sec' => $_POST['select_access2'],
    'accs_admin_sec' => $_POST['select_access3'],
    'accs_dashboard_sec' => $_POST['select_access4'],
    'accs_reports_sec' => $_POST['select_access5']
  );
  $this->RoleModel->saveRole($basic_data);
```

**Model**

```
public function saveRole($basic_data){
    return $this->db->insert('roles_global_access', $basic_data);
}
```

Comment: i use ajax to pass the value 1|0|1|

Comment: Add complete code in your question and table structure.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I can't insert the value of my checkbox to different column

Comment: what is the result of this print_r($basic_data);

Comment: you can use codeiginter to save the value of checkbox why you using ajax?

Comment: this is my ajax to pass the value 1 or 0 of my checkbox

Comment: is your `$_POST` has values in it? @Chris

Comment: Didn't mean the html itself. I mean the `$_POST` that you pass to your Controller

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id='ckbox' class="checkbox" name='select_access1[' value="1"/>  this value is passed to controller itself using this _POST(select_access1)

Comment: check the picture that I upload

Comment: @Chris can you add your JS code on this post? You need to use ajax to pass data from JS to PHP.

Comment: $('button').on("click",function(){

var cList = "";

$('.checkbox').each(function(){

var cThisVal = (this.checked ? "1" : "0");

cList += (cList=="" ? cThisVal : "," + cThisVal);});



var datastring= cList;

//alert(datastring);

 $.ajax({

type: "POST",

url: "<?php echo base_url('Role/insertNewRole'); ?>",

data: datastring,

cache: false,

success: function (data) {

//alert(data;
}
});
});

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548173/how-to-insert-the-value-on-my-checkbox-to-different-column-on-my-database

check this one

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

Controller:

```
$this->RoleModel->saveRole($_POST);
```

Model:

```
    public function saveRole($basic_data){
           extract($basic_data);
           $dataset = array(
            'accs_trans_sec' => $basic_data['select_access1'],
            'accs_acctng_sec' => $basic_data['select_access2'],
            'accs_admin_sec' => $basic_data['select_access3'],
            'accs_dashboard_sec' => $basic_data['select_access4'],
            'accs_reports_sec' => $basic_data['select_access5']
          );
          $this->db->insert('roles_global_access', $dataset);
    }
```