# How to insert the value on my checkbox to different column on my database?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

This my current output -

[image]

And my Ajax code is like this -

[image]

There's no error. but it can't pass through my database

**MY CONTROLLER**

```
public function insertNewRole(){
    $basic_data = array();

    $basic_data = array(
        'accs_trans_sec' => $_POST['select_access1'],
        'accs_acctng_sec' => $_POST['select_access2'],
        'accs_admin_sec' => $_POST['select_access3'],
        'accs_dashboard_sec' => $_POST['select_access4'],
        'accs_reports_sec' => $_POST['select_access5']
    );
    $this->RoleModel->saveRole($basic_data);
}
```

Comment: wait, what is the value of `base_url` on your script?

Comment: Your code is open to sql injections as you are using `$_POST`

Comment: @roshan its a path going through controller

Answer (score 0):

I just see the issue here. 
I see that `datastring` variable is an string that each value is separated by `,` that you just use to post on your controller right?
So it will be `$_POST['data']` on your controller.

Then try to use `explode()` like this on your controller:

**`$parseddata = explode(',',$_POST['data']);`**

Let's continue to your code:

```
   public function insertNewRole(){

    $parseddata = explode(',',$_POST['data']);

     $basic_data = array();

    $basic_data = array(
        'accs_trans_sec' => $parseddata[0], //The value should be 1
        'accs_acctng_sec' => $parseddata[1],//The value should be 0
        'accs_admin_sec' => $parseddata[2], //The value should be 1
        'accs_dashboard_sec' => $parseddata[3], //The value should be 0
        'accs_reports_sec' => $parseddata[4] //The value should be 1
    );
    $result = $this->RoleModel->saveRole($basic_data);

     if($result == true){
          echo ("Successfully inserted!");
     }else{
           echo ("Problem!");
      }
}
```

Let's see if you can get through this.

> **EDIT:** Based on your previous post, your model has a loop on it, I modify it and should like this:

```
public function saveRole($basic_data)
   {
    $this->db->insert('roles_global_access', $basic_data);

    return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
   }
```

Comment: public function saveRole($basic_data)
  {
     $basic_data = array();
     
      $basic_data = array(
      'accs_trans_sec' => $select_access1,
      'accs_acctng_sec' => $select_access2,
      'accs_admin_sec' => $select_access3,
      'accs_dashboard_sec' => $select_access4,
      'accs_reports_sec' => $select_access5
    );

     $this->db->insert("roles_global_access", $basic_data);
 }

Comment: Hello, I edited my answer, please see updated answer.